How Can Angular Signals be Integrated into ngxs Selector State Management?
Am using ngxs state management and have the following state and selectors:
export interface ITodoCountState {
  count: string;
}

@State<ITodoCountState>({
  name: 'todosCount',
  defaults: {
    count: '',
  },
})
@Injectable()
export class TodoCountState {
  @Selector([TodoCountState])
  static count(state: ITodoCountState) {
    return state.count;
  }

  @Action(SetTodosCount)
  GetTodosCount(ctx: StateContext<ITodoCountState>, action: SetTodosCount) {
    ctx.patchState({
      count: action.count,
    });
  }
}

And then in my component have it like this:
@Select(TodoCountState.count) todosCount$!: Observable<string>;

todosCount$ is directly used in my html template.
How can I use Angular Signals for todosCount$?

I have implemented is the toSignal method that comes with angular. I am using facades to communicate views with the store, and at that level I have put something like:
@Select(TodoCountState.count) todosCount$!: Observable<string>;
$todosCount = toSignal(this.todosCount$, {initialValue: ""})

Then I decide in the view if I need the observable or the signal.

thank you but looking for a way to remove the Observable I mean todosCount$! and only have a signal type variable

NGXS provides a way of getting Selectors as signals, try
todoCount = select(TodoCountState.count); 

